# Is "vernissage" in common use in American English?

Tags: nouns

I'm translating a novel from Swedish to English. The book is slightly above the level of chick-lit, so I don't want it to sound too fancy. In Swedish vernissage is a common word. I have personally never heard or used this term in English.

Comment: There are [12 cites in all of COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31776709), so no, you can't call it common by any stretch of imagination.

Comment: I've never heard it at all. Also, Swedish is not a common loan source for English, even less so by way of France. Except for the Normans. And Vikings. OK forget all that. Vernissage is crazy rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a native speaker of AmE, widely read and for decades active in artsy circles, and I have never heard this in conversation; I haven't seen it in writing more than half a dozen times.

You may put it in the mouth of characters who are eager to display their familiarity with the upper reaches of arts marketing and consumption; otherwise I would use *private showing* or *preview*.

ADDED:
JanusBahsJacquet suggests that in Swedish a *vernissage* is not a private preview, as it is in English, but the *opening* of an exhibition with, I presume, attendant festivities.

Note that the French original means *varnishing* and (in English usage, at least) referred to the day before the official opening, when artists mounted their works and applied a final finish coat of varnish, to protect the work and give it a fashionable glow. The modern English sense derives from the practice of admitting favoured connoisseurs to this activity.

Comment: Note that, if I'm not mistaken, _vernissage_ in Swedish refers not to a pre-opening preview, but to the actual _official opening_ itself, so in the asker's particular situation, ***opening*** may be a better translation. (That's not strictly related to the on-topic part of the question, though.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet These French terms of art seem unstable; I've just discovered what has happened to *charrette* in English over the past forty years. It used to mean the mad scramble to get your work ready for viewing; now it's an intense planning period.

Comment: The jargon used by a small field of workers is notoriously quick to change with time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Vernissage%2Cvermissage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVernissage%3B%2Cc0) it is not. Very little  use appears from it. As far as I know it is [common](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/vernissage) in countries like France and Italy.

> A vernissage (varnishing, from French) is a term used for a preview of an art exhibition, which may be private, before the formal opening.[1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Vernissage%2Cvermissage&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVernissage%3B%2Cc0) Guests may be served canapés and wine as they discuss with artists and others the works in the exhibition. If the vernissage is not open to the public, but only for invited guests, it is often called a private view.